# How to retrieve the deleted Partition table on linux?

Tags: ubuntu, parted

I'm using the Ubuntu server. RAID 0 based logical volume was working fine on our server, but suddenly on restart of that server, the partition table is got deleted. Having some important data in that drive. Please help me to retrieve the data. Is there a possible ways to recover the deleted partition table back.?

In **Parted** tool, I have checked for the available partition table, and it shown empty value.

Comment: Is this a RAID0 created through `mdadm` or one that was set up in the BIOS/UEFI subsystem? You say it held important data, so have you got your backup to hand? You may need it

Comment: It was created by the UEFI subsystem, not by the OS.